# Implicitly generate move constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, move-semantics

Is there any way a move constructor for a move-only class can be implicitly generated? Consider a class like this:

```
class moveable_only
{
  unique_ptr<int> p_;
};

moveable_only m;
foo(std::move(m));
```

This doesn't compile, because the implicitly declared copy constructor cannot copy p_. (12.8/7)

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared  implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4).

Now consider this:

```
class moveable_only
{
  unique_ptr<int> p_;
  
   moveable_only(const moveable_only&);
   moveable_only& operator = (const moveable_only&);
};

moveable_only m;
foo(std::move(m));
```

This doesn't compile as well, because of 12.8/9

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
>
> — the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This doesn't compile, because the implicitly declared copy constructor cannot copy p_. (12.8/7)

There is no need for a copy constructor. This does not compile because your compiler does not seem to generate a move constructor automatically, *which it should*.

There is no way around that other than implementing it yourself or updating the compiler.

Comment: Okay, so if my compiler doesn't support this feature yet, I'm basically doomed to always fully write the move constructor and move assignment operator?

Comment: @cooky I edited in a possible way to reduce the amount of code repetition.

Comment: Well I don't really understand what you mean with writing a copyable unique_ptr with the behavior I want, I don't want it to be copyable. ^^

Comment: Oh, wait. I seem to have misunderstood something in your question then. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ah okay, so this is likely a VS11 bug? I get a "This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function ..." error message. Quite an annoying bug to say the least.

Comment: @cooky451 : VS11 is simply targeting an older draft of the standard; it's less of a bug and more of a not-yet-implemented feature. See [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) for details.